# Question concerning types, Maps and subclasses in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics, types

I have a `Chart` class which has several subclasses (`BarChart`, `TimeseriesChart`...) which extend `Chart`.
I use a method called `buildChart` to build these charts. It maps the enum `ChartsEnum` (for example `stackedTimeseries` or `barChart`) to the correct class using a Map:

```
export function buildChart(type: Charts, data: Array<TimeseriesData>) {
   
   var chartsMap = new Map<Charts, InstantiableAbstractClass<typeof Chart>([
        [Charts.stackedTimeseries, TimeseriesChart],
        [Charts.barChart, BarChart],
    ])
    const chart = chartsMap.get(type)
    return new chart(data).chart;

}
```

The type InstantiableAbstractClass looks like this:

```
export declare type InstantiableClass<T> = (new ( ...args: any) => { [x: string]: any }) & T;
```

For example, the class and constructor of `TimeseriesChart` looks like this:

```
export class TimeseriesChart extends Chart{
    constructor(data: Array<TimeseriesData>) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```

I now want to add a second attribute to the `chart`-class called `options` (next to the existing attribute `data`).
The problem is now that `options` requires for each ChartType (`BarChart`, `TimeseriesChart`) different properties.
For example `BarChart` requires these properties:

```
{
    start: number;
    end?: number;
}
```

and `TimeseriesChart` requires a type like this:

```
{
    description: string;
}
```

The constructor of `TimeseriesChart` would then look like this:

```
export class TimeseriesChart extends Chart{
    constructor(data: Array<TimeseriesData>, options: TimeseriesChartOptions) {
        super(data, options);
    }
}
```

This means that the method `buildChart` needs a new argument `options` which can then be passed to the specific classes (as done with the argument `data`).

What is the best way for doing this? I thought of using generics and then defining n types of types for `options` for n subclasses, but I could not figure out on how to change the type InstantiableAbstractClass correctly for that.

You can find a complete example with some descriptions [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgLybN).

I really appreciate your help! If you need any further information I would be happy to provide them.

Thank you and all the best
Lukas

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mqvGJW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared/unimported types or values.

Comment: Hi @jcalz, I edited the code and I hope that everything works fine now. You can find it [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAV4vW)

Comment: I'll take a look when I can, but you should [edit] the question directly with your updated code and any links.

Comment: In the comments you say "I would like that only `options` only accepts objects of the type `TimeseriesChartOptions`" but I don't know what `TimeseriesChartOptions` is, you didn't define it.  Ideally a [mre] should have concrete examples where something is different from how you want it where the undesirable result is highlighted in some way (e.g., there's an error where there shouldn't be, or vice versa).

Comment: Hi @jcalz . Sorry for the circumstances and thank you for your patience :D [Here](https://tsplay.dev/wgLybN) is the updated playground. I hope that it now provides all the required information.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wzo23w) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate in the question about unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Yes! This answers my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it seems like you want your `Chart` class to be [`abstract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members) since you are only ever going to use concrete subclasses of it, and you want the `buildChart()` method to throw if not overridden.  I'm also going to use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) as a shorthand for declaring a field and an idential constructor parameter and assigning the latter to the former.  I'm adding an `options` parameter of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) because we don't really need any type checking in the base class like this.

```
abstract class Chart {
    constructor(protected data: Array<TimeseriesData>, protected options: any) { }
    abstract buildChart(): void;
}
```

Anyway, for the subclasses, we will narrow the `options` property to the appropriate type by using [the `declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier), and specify that type in the constructor parameter also:

```
interface BarChartOptions {
    start: number,
    end: number
}
class BarChart extends Chart {
    declare options: BarChartOptions;
    constructor(data: Array<TimeseriesData>, options: BarChartOptions) {
        super(data, options);
    }
    buildChart() { return {}; }
    protected getChartData() { }
}


interface TimeseriesChartOptions {
    description: string
}

class TimeseriesChart extends Chart {
    declare options: TimeseriesChartOptions;
    constructor(data: Array<TimeseriesData>, options: TimeseriesChartOptions) {
        super(data, options);
    }
    buildChart() { return { }; }
    protected getChartData() { }
}
```

Now we need to express the relationship between your `Charts` enum and the different subclasses.  Let's make a `chartConstructors` object holding the enums as keys and the constructors as values:

```
const chartConstructors = {
    [Charts.stackedTimeseries]: TimeseriesChart,
    [Charts.barChart]: BarChart
}
```

You should add an entry to that for each subclass of `Chart` you care about.

---

Finally we will write your `buildChart()` function.  Let's make some helper types:

```
type ChartConstructorParameters<C extends Charts> = 
  ConstructorParameters<typeof chartConstructors[C]>;
type ChartInstance<C extends Charts> = 
  InstanceType<typeof chartConstructors[C]>;
type ChartConstructor<C extends Charts> = 
  new (...args: ChartConstructorParameters<C>) => ChartInstance<C>;
```

The `ChartConstructorParameters<C>` type will take an enum member as `C` and turn it into the [tuple of arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to the relevant class constructor, using [the `ConstructorParameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype).

The `ChartInstance<C>` type does the same thing for the instance type of the relevant class constructor, using [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype).

And finally the `ChartConstructor<C>` represents the relevant [constructor signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) for the class.

And now here's `buildChart()`:

```
function buildChart<C extends Charts>(
  type: C, ...ctorArgs: ChartConstructorParameters<C>
) {
    const chartConstructor = chartConstructors[type] as ChartConstructor<C>;
    return new chartConstructor(...ctorArgs);
}
```

It's a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) which takes a `type` parameter of generic type `C` corresponding to an enum member.  And for the remaining arguments, it takes whatever the constructor parameters of the relevant class is.  This will be a pair of `data` and `options` for the `BarChart` and `TimeseriesChart`, but if you add subclasses with other constructor parameters, it will accept those.

The output is an instance of the class, which it constructs by grabbing the relevant constructor from `chartConstructors` (we need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that `chartConstructors[type]` is actually of the type `ChartConstructor<C>`; it's something the compiler is unable to see due to its inability to reason too much about unspecified generic types like `C`).

---

So, does it work?

```
const barChart = buildChart(Charts.barChart, [], { start: 1, end: 2 });
// const barChart: BarChart

const timeSeriesChart = buildChart(Charts.stackedTimeseries, [], { description: "" });
// const timeSeriesChart: TimeseriesChart
```

Yes, looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrALYQM7WDgETjDmQG8BYAKGVuTExxIwAcAuZEAVwwCNoA3NTrIAbnAA2XCB259B1AL7U4vbGCiIwyBBLjZsyAMIALOFG2UadBAHsQ6qFwRhbUABQsotyC4gATZH9iOA4AQShNAE8AHnQsXCh8bCISAD4AGmQvHwg-QNsWBntsDjgQKIBKcmRla1pVRy1kXi5gCX9TczB3So5RW2B-ISo66lBIWEQUACFzLosAeSLgEvJhOnVu2R5+KAyN2ggQfx35KCVqXX1DOagF7QgAD0gTwwf1+qC8vSgUQuKDg4dwey0B2BGIjsDg0zlcHmCJHCkTgsXiODwhBCmWQANWQOQILMSxWJWqVhEImwXBY0HciLgWTxZMhdDqIla7U6xJ65MOlL+YC4UBAn0p4uQAHpJchBcLRTBQJIdDydPZFQBzZCKiQQfkiRQjfnsug5XyQQIaiBgB6pOC9MUS6XIK1gQwIVUM43850wYVgEzQZBYAO2fzu2wYUBawN-FpcbQBiBRZDmFAgHyyiC68TgS5UajjcDQeBINCMRLJUGkhyO2j+HAIJI1jiOaP5q56AzlhKY7AfZ6vcPGVUUugN65x5kE9GVnDV8Gs2jQxxwtz0kLI6JxCt9u046elHsYpLznlg-HYPlfKk0ukMpk1q9L2r8zkdB4OsfiuUiusS2hnV-BUlQkFVujVEBNW1do9RvNkjS+E1aDNPILRda1bRCL99ToZ1XXdT0Qm9L5fX9WNg2tEwwwjKMQBjaAUFaRNAxTNNOEzP4c3KMAOwLfjjh4EdukMMhkAAci2BAAGsAlnPtxKycTeHmHlxNffjnRpREUADYBDAAd0DUUQDyHBsHMKIrhKbQPW6IwbKcFw3EMABef8AG0HmwAA6KTZP8eTT2wABdDggqrHkDi+LyeV8lT7h5MLCVU7o+OoMAolpYSLAcmEnPhAAFcw4BDaBsBiIxkEHY5h28tJkHcvLV2cqBis0MqoAqzLaVsGBwNyxy1y6ryQrSEYepQB4AEkYXKJBKuql5aveOKGvc2athAJBUCyiAYkmvqBptIbWuwUbxoyvacpO-LhsWmq3hu7B1s4CADOQdwfO+8wNSPB5mthVr2tK61ysqtJqlchqZrm7b9qMS7+L9bbAXjLkHge5anvq9xJo4Iwsm+nzWoiP6CZ5QGCrcEHOoqxHryhGzjqp4bGpZ074XOyaQtTVb7M5twIZfYC3o+uzBru1qvu+0moD+yoRjGKgV20BKPnc99uW6dxvJ89WouQDyQqyMStgsDgAEYslqjgACZakV6hnVVlpUotlLErS-jXYYLAAGU+w19GPx5XW4r8kgZLk3dgqyY3Te+bAm2AFtkAAInTx2Rhd5m-YgQPgoecLY8i7ogA)